# solr, query nested childs documents

Tags: solr

Is not very clear to me how to use [Solr with nested child documents](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/searching-nested-documents.html).
I want to index in Solr the text extracted from epub files, at chapter level. So this is an example document

```json
{
    "id": "f4006f18-ed97-11ed-a3ba-dfa63040a09b",
    "title_txt": "title of my book",
    "isbn_s": "1234-5678",
    "epub_s": "/books/book.epub",
    "type_s": "book",
    "subjects_ss": ["subject1", "subject2"],
    "chapters":
    [
        {
            "id": "04aac124-218c-468b-a746-2c60a5ee9969",
            "title_txt": "chapter 1",
            "pos_i": 1,
            "text_txt_it": "chapter 1 long text",
            "element_id_s": "",
            "file_s": "file_1.xhtml",
            "type_s": "chapter"
        },
        {
            "id": "d8cd1e22-a628-4e06-b4ff-0cf8c65d3db2",
            "title_txt": "chapter 2",
            "pos_i": 2,
            "text_txt_it": "chapter 2 long text",
            "element_id_s": "",
            "file_s": "file_2.xhtml",
            "type_s": "chapter"
        }
    ]
}
```

That which I would like to achieve: query `text_txt_it` of `type_s:chapter` documents and:

1. obtain highlights
2. faceting on `type_s:book` `subjects_ss` field

So questions:

1. Is this the right way to model in Solr this kind of data?
2. Can I do everything with a single query or I need to use multiple query from app to do collapsing and faceting?

I'm trying this query but the **faceting is not working**:

```
http://localhost:18983/solr/ebooks/select
    ?indent=true
    &q.op=OR
    &q=text_txt_it:"query"
    &rows=100
    &fl=id
    &facet=true
    &facet.field={!parent which='type_s:book'}subject_ss
    &facet.mincount=1
    &hl=on 
    &hl.fl=text_txt_it 
    &hl.snippets=15 
    &hl.fragsize=1
    &hl.simple.pre="<mark>"
```